# glib GHashtable dereference gpointer

Tags: c, pointers, glib, dereference

Hi This issues related to GLib, gpointer.

I create a value with gpointer type.

```
    gpointer        keys;
```

I called a function

```
insert_data(gpointer key);
```

I passed the integer pointer to this function like that.

```
int* p = malloc(sizeof(int));
*p = 1;
// gpointer is void* pointer, I cast it to integer type pointer here.
insert_data(p);
```

Inside the function I want to see the value of p.

```
printf("%d\n", (int*)p);
```

It outputs some very large number.From my side it is 296304, no the actually value 1.
I want to know how to dereference a pointer like gpointer.

For integer 32 bits pointer, char* pointer, how to dereference them?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to print the pointer itself. Technically, this is [*undefined behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) since you are using the wrong format specifier to print a pointer. What you observe is the integer interpretation of the pointer `p`.

Change

```
printf("%d\n", (int*)p);
```

to

```
printf("%d\n", *(int*)p);
```

Or you can do:

```
insert_data(gpointer ptr)
{
  int *p = ptr;
  printf("%d\n", *p);
  ...
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. If I have a char* p = NULL; p = strdup("one");                                              I called the insert_data(gpointer ptr) function like insert_data(p); I can print the pointer like printf("%s\n", p); or printf("%s\n", (char*)p). It works fine and print "one". Why not use printf("%s\n", \*(char\*)p)  same as the integer pointer? Could you explain it a little bit more on that? thanks.

Comment: It's not the same. `%s` expects a `char*`. So `printf("%s\n", (char*)p)` works fine. But `%d` expects an integer (int specifically), so you need to pass an `int`. `*(char*)p)` would be the value of the first char pointer to by `p` i.e. `o` in `"one"`. So it won't work.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.

Comment: GLib also has some macros to make shoving ints in pointers slightly cleaner: `gpointer aptr = GINT_TO_POINTER (5); gint anum = GPOINTER_TO_INT(aptr);`